# Error on Save a Image from a URL with CURL, encoded content

Tags: curl, image-processing, download, character-encoding, encode

Hello guys I am trying to get a image from a URL to a folder on my server, but I am having a lot of troubles with this procedure. I know that the content of this url(the IMAGE) is in another charset, or some thing like that, I just know that it show a lot of chinese letter on preview, and a lot  strange letter on response. The code is:

```
        $ch = curl_init ($URL);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0');
        $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);

       * $charsets = array("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1","GB2312"); 
       * var_dump(mb_detect_encoding($rawdata,$charsets));
       * var_dump($rawdata);

        $fp = fopen($local_file,'w'); 
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp) 

  //  * -> trying to debbug
```

The answer of this request is:

• on the preview (the first and the second line are my var_dumps)
[The preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp0G2.png)

• on the response (the first and the second line are my var_dumps)
[the response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLF8S.png)

When I try to apply this code on a URL where the image doesn't have this kind of special characters it work very well and make the download to my server... But when the answer have those chineses letters it doesn't copy the image to my folder.

Comment: you're so confused, the weird characters you see is your browser attempting to render JPG binary as text (ASCII or UTF-8 or whatever), remove the var_dump's, and run `header("content-type: image/jpeg"); echo $rawdata;` instead, and you tell the browser `this is a JPG image, render it as such`, and the browser will try to render it as a jpg image instead of text, and you will probably get a picture. :)

Comment: I didn't insert all the code, sorry! before this part there is a regex function to get the type of the file 
            `preg_match("/(.png|.jpg)/", $url, $IMG_type);
            $local_file = $IMG_destiny.$Name_PROD."-".$IMG_type;`
And the charset of this image it is a kind of chinese, it is not a normal JPG binary as text, click on this link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp0G2.png) to see. I have changed for "wb" on fopen(). thank you so much to help me!!

Comment: a JPG image does not have a charset. sure, there may be some chinese-charset text as embedded metadata, but the jpg binary format doesn't have any charset at all.

Comment: show me an actual url serving 1 of the files you're actually trying to download/display, and i'll check it out for myself and let you know wtf is going on

Comment: I am trying to download these two images, the first I have no problems to make the download, but the seconds it doesn't work
1- w1.ezcdn.com.br/ventureshop/fotos/grande/6fg1/besta-profissional-jaguar-black-175lbs-quiver-oculos.jpg // 2 - w1.ezcdn.com.br/ventureshop/fotos/grande/8fg1/adaptador-mount-p-pesca-c-besta-ams-bowfishing.jpg

Comment: try ```<?php header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); $ch=curl_init("http://w1.ezcdn.com.br/ventureshop/fotos/grande/8fg1/adaptador-mount-p-pesca-c-besta-ams-bowfishing.jpg"); curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);$img=curl_exec($ch);curl_close($ch);echo $img;$fp=fopen("image.jpg","wb");fwrite($fp,$img);fclose($fp);```

Answer (score 0):

you're so confused, the weird characters you see is your browser attempting to render JPG binary data as text (ASCII or unicode or whatever). remove the var_dump's, and run

```
header("content-type: image/jpeg"); 
echo $rawdata;
```

instead, and you tell the browser `this is a JPG image, render it as such`, and the browser will try to render it as a jpg image instead of text, and you will probably get a picture. :)

also, you're using a dangerous non-portable fopen mode, replace the `w` with `wb` in `$fp=fopen($local_file,'w');` , and it will be portable (your current fopen mode will work fine in linux/mac/bsd -based OSs, but will wreak havoc on Microsoft Windows-based operating systems, which has an implicit "text mode", where `\n` is automatically converted to `\r\n`, but changing to `wb` changes it into binary mode, even on Windows-based systems.)